# How to wrap text inside a text box using D3js and textwrap.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found this great plug-in, textwrap.js that wrap long lines of svg text.  I'm using this plug-in with d3js.  I was able to create my text boxes and text using d3 and json object.  But when I apply the textwrap.js function the text will wrap as expected but it will relocate the text from the text box and place the text in the top left corner of the browser screen; ignoring the x and y positioning I established in the d3 selectAll text structure.  Textwrap.js won't wrap the text and keep it in the text box.  I played with several techniques to wrap the text and keep it in its specific text box but I found no joy.  I attached my current code that places the wrapped text in the top left corner.  I really appreciate any help to resolve this issue (placing the wrapped text inside the text box).  Thank you in advance.

link to textwrap.js documentation:  https://github.com/kstohr/d3textwrap

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<head>

  <title>Text Wrap Practice</title>


<link href="myCSS_Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js "></script>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="textwrap.js"></script><!---->
<script src="myJS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="chartData"></div>

</body>

</html>

$(document).ready(function(){

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("#chartData").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)


d3.json("data.json", function(json) {
       var elem = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(json.nodes)

    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g")

    var circle = elemEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x} )
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y} )
        .attr("width", function(d){return d.w} )
        .attr("height", function(d){return d.h} )
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .attr("fill", "white")

    elemEnter.append("text")
        .attr("class",  function(d) { return "txtElem" + d.id; })
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x + 50} )
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y + 40} )
        .text(function(d){return d.label});

var wrap = d3.textwrap().bounds({height: 50, width: 250}); 

        d3.selectAll('text').call(wrap);



});
```

Data File, data.json:

{"nodes":[
  {"id":1, "x":80,  "y":40,  "w":250, "h":50, "label":"This is my long text 1 that need to be wrapped by textwrap"}, 
  {"id":2, "x":200, "y":160, "w":250, "h":50, "label":"Long Text 2 I like to wrap in the text box"}, 
  {"id":3, "x":380, "y":280, "w":250, "h":50, "label":"My Long Text 3 I'm try to wrap into the text box"}
]}

Comment: This is a feature I was toying with that I picked up from reading the text wrap documentation.  But due to my limited skills I can't seem to get it to work properly.  I think this maybe a clue to a possible solution. d3.select('text').textwrap(function(d, i) {
         // code to dynamically determine bounds
        // for each text node goes here
  
 });

Answer (score 0):

I can *force it to work* if I call it like this:

```
d3.selectAll("text").each(function(){
  d3.select(this).textwrap(this.previousElementSibling.getBBox());
});
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Text Wrap Practice</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/kstohr/d3textwrap/master/d3textwrap.v0.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chartData"></div>
    <script>
  var width = 960,
    height = 500;

  var svg = d3.select("#chartData").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  //d3.json("data.json", function(json) {
    
    var json = {"nodes":[{"id":1,"x":80,"y":40,"w":250,"h":50,"label":"This is my long text 1 that need to be wrapped by textwrap"},{"id":2,"x":200,"y":160,"w":250,"h":50,"label":"Long Text 2 I like to wrap in the text box"},{"id":3,"x":380,"y":280,"w":250,"h":50,"label":"My Long Text 3 I'm try to wrap into the text box"}]};
    
    var elem = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(json.nodes)

    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
      .append("g")

    var circle = elemEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.w
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.h
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("fill", "white")

    var textElements = elemEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "txtElem" + d.id;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x + 50
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y + 40
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label
      });

    d3.selectAll("text").each(function(){
      d3.select(this).textwrap(this.previousElementSibling.getBBox());
    })

//});

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

To be honest, though, I find the plugin to be confusing and of dubious quality.  When I need to wrap text I usually follow this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

I'd refactor your code a bit and that example and in the end my code would look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Text Wrap Practice</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/kstohr/d3textwrap/master/d3textwrap.v0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chartData"></div>
  <script>
    var width = 960,
      height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select("#chartData").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    //d3.json("data.json", function(json) {

    var json = {
      "nodes": [{
        "id": 1,
        "x": 80,
        "y": 40,
        "w": 250,
        "h": 50,
        "label": "This is my long text 1 that need to be wrapped by textwrap"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "x": 200,
        "y": 160,
        "w": 250,
        "h": 50,
        "label": "Long Text 2 I like to wrap in the text box"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "x": 380,
        "y": 280,
        "w": 250,
        "h": 50,
        "label": "My Long Text 3 I'm try to wrap into the text box"
      }]
    };

    var elem = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(json.nodes)

    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      })

    var circle = elemEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.w
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.h
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("fill", "white")

    var textElements = elemEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "txtElem" + d.id;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label
      })
      .attr("y", 12);

    d3.selectAll("text").call(wrap, function(d) {
      return this.previousElementSibling.getBBox().width;
    });

    function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
          y = text.attr("y"),
          dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")) || 0,
          tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

        width = (typeof width === "function") ? width.call(this) : width;

        while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    //});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mark Wonderful...this is it.!  Exactly what I was trying to accomplish!!!  I really appreciate your help.  This solution is going to help me big time with a product at work.